# Cant load WebView in JavaFX 2.0 and 8.0

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I tried to run the following code in my Netbeans 7.2 (Java 1.7.u79) and Netbeans 8.0.2 (Java 1.8 u45) and its not working!

```
package com.main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class RBrowser extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            WebView browser = new WebView();
            final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm");

            Button b = new Button("Show Console");
            b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                    webEngine.executeScript("if (!document.getElementById('FirebugLite')){E = document['createElement' + 'NS'] && document.documentElement.namespaceURI;E = E ? document['createElement' + 'NS'](E, 'script') : document['createElement']('script');E['setAttribute']('id', 'FirebugLite');E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + 'firebug-lite.js' + '#startOpened');E['setAttribute']('FirebugLite', '4');(document['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0] || document['getElementsByTagName']('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E = new Image;E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + '#startOpened');}");
                }
            });

            VBox root = new VBox();
            root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            root.getChildren().addAll(browser,b);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 550);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Google Map");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

I tried to access `http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm` in the Google Chrome Browser and it was loaded successfully, **WHAT'S WRONG WITH MY CODE?**

Comment: Can you give the details of the response you get ?
Is there an error, or some output we can see please ?

Comment: BTW It works for me in NetBeans 8.1

Comment: Code here works perfectly too. Running on Eclipse Mars2, with Java 1.8.0_74, on Mac OSX Capitan.  Any console errors/output?

Comment: There is no error in the console, but I got a lot of JDK installation in my PC, will these affect the WebView behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JDK have you installed. I am using IDK 8u77 on Windows 8.1 and running on Eclipse Mars2 your code, it worked perfectly. Try [latest version from here.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) Check it works or not.